# Change an array MATCH/PERCENTILE formula from indexing out of 5 to out of 10

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, excel-2013

I have the following two array function code snippets, the first used when a high value is 'good', the second when a low value is 'good':

```
=MATCH(E2,PERCENTILE(E:E,{0,1,2,3,4}/5),1)

=MATCH(F2,PERCENTILE(F:F,{5,4,3,2,1}/5),-1)
```

The current output indexes values in E:E, F:F from one to five. I'd like to increase this to being 'from one to ten'. I don't really understand *how* the array works, so am really struggling.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want may be:

```
=MATCH(E2,PERCENTILE(E:E,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}/10),1)
```

and

```
=MATCH(F2,PERCENTILE(F:F,{10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1}/10),-1)
```